# How do I fetch the static front page using the REST API?

Tags: front-end, frontpage, rest-api

I would like to create an Angular 2 SPA that uses the WordPress REST API as a back-end. How can I use the API to fetch the page the user has set as their front page?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you asking how to create a custom REST endpoint in a plugin, or are you asking how to get the page the user has set as the frontpage in code? ( If the answer is both, you will want to ask 2 separate questions for maximum effectiveness, we have a 1 question per question policy here )

Comment: The later, I was wondering if it was possible to programmatically fetch the page that is configured to be the static front page. I have just got it working actually by using an additional plugin I'll post the code up now.

Answer (score 8):

We could implement our own endpoint:

```
https://example.tld/wpse/v1/frontpage
```

Here's a simple demo (*PHP 5.4+*):

```
<?php
/** 
 * Plugin Name: WPSE - Static Frontpage Rest Endpoint
 */
namespace WPSE\RestAPI\Frontpage;

\add_action( 'rest_api_init', function()
{
    \register_rest_route( 'wpse/v1', '/frontpage/', 
        [
            'methods'   => 'GET',
            'callback'  => __NAMESPACE__.'\rest_results'
        ] 
    );
} );

function rest_results( $request )
{
    // Get the ID of the static frontpage. If not set it's 0
    $pid  = (int) \get_option( 'page_on_front' );    

    // Get the corresponding post object (let's show our intention explicitly)
    $post = ( $pid > 0 ) ? \get_post( $pid ) : null;  

    // No static frontpage is set
    if( ! is_a( $post, '\WP_Post' ) )
        return new \WP_Error( 'wpse-error', 
           \esc_html__( 'No Static Frontpage', 'wpse' ), [ 'status' => 404 ] );

    // Response setup
    $data = [
        'ID'      => $post->ID,
        'content' => [ 'raw' => $post->post_content ]
    ];

    return new \WP_REST_Response( $data, 200 );     
}
```

A successful response is like:

```
{"ID":123,"content":{"raw":"Some content"}}
```

and an error response is like:

```
{"code":"wpse-error","message":"No Static Frontpage","data":{"status":404}}
```

Then we can extend it to support other fields or *rendered* content by applying the `the_content` filter.

Comment: What's up with the \back_slashes?

Comment: When using namespace, I use it to access the global functions and classes, but hat's not always neccessary. For example if I would define my own `get_post()` function, then I would have to use `\get_post()` to call the WordPress core version. If I don't define my own `get_post()`, then `get_post()` will call the WordPress core function.  WordPress is currently not using any  namespace either.  I decided to backslash mostly everyting here , just for the sake of consistancy, since this is just a small code snippet ;-) @jgraup

Comment: I figured for namespaces, just didn't ever think of redefining something like 'get_post' unless on a class. Learn something new each day.

Comment: Sometimes it's handy to define a function with a short handy name that's already taken. I guess there's also a fine line between consistancy and "backslash spam" ;-) Usually I just do it when it's neccessary, somehow the "consistancy" urge got hold of me here ;-)  @jgraup

Answer (score 2):

Because I build several Polymer & Angular SPA's for the frontend with WordPress backends I've created a plugin for this purpose https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-frontpage/

I hope this helps...

Basically it extends the native REST API with a new route:

```
wp-json/wp/v2/frontpage
```

Cheers!

Comment: Congratulation with your plugin release. Few remarks: 1) probably better to use own namespace instead of `wp/v2` that's used by core 2) same goes for the `WP_` class prefix 3) `file_get_contents()` adds extra request and might not always work for url requests 4) there's still a `wpse` textdomain and `wpse-error` used in the code that doesn't match the `wp-rest-api-frontpage` plugin text domain.  cheers

Comment: @birgire: Thanks for the quick 'code-review'. Will definitely take it into account!

Answer (score 2):

This happens to be very simple.  WordPress doesn't have frontpage endpoint by default but you can create one like this.

```
// Register Front Page route.
// URL will be: domainname.ext/wp-json/my-namespace/v1/frontpage/
register_rest_route(
  'my-namespace/v1', '/frontpage',
  array(
      'methods'  => 'GET',
      'callback' => [ $this, 'get_frontpage' ],
  )
);


// Callback function.
function get_frontpage( $object ) {

  // Get WP options front page from settings > reading.
  $frontpage_id = get_option('page_on_front');

  // Handle if error.
  if ( empty( $frontpage_id ) ) {
    // return error
    return 'error';
  }

  // Create request from pages endpoint by frontpage id.
  $request  = new \WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/pages/' . $frontpage_id );

  // Parse request to get data.
  $response = rest_do_request( $request );

  // Handle if error.
  if ( $response->is_error() ) {
     return 'error';
  }

  return $response->get_data();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just got this working using the plugin 'WP API Options' plugin. You can find the plugin here:
https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-options/

It allows you to see which page has been configured as the front page. Below is a TypeScript code snippet that uses the 'wp-api-angular' package.

```
getFrontPage(): Promise<any> {
    return this.wpApiPages
      .httpGet('/options/page_on_front')
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(body => body.page_on_front)
      .then(frontPageId => this.wpApiPages
        .get(frontPageId)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json()))
      .catch(error => {});
}
```